# android.view.WindowLeaked exception

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I'm reading xml data from a url. It worked well when it was it portrait mode. But I wanted to change it to landscape mode. But it gets android.view.WindowLeaked exception.

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance. This is my code.

```
package com.eisuru.abc;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tvResponse;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        tvResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResponse); 
        new PostAsync().execute(); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    class PostAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { 
        ProgressDialog pd; XMLHelper helper;     
        @Override 
        protected void onPreExecute() { 
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Exchange Rates", "Loading Exchange rates values ...", true, false);
            } 

        @Override 
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) { 
            helper = new XMLHelper(); helper.get(); 
            return null; 
            }   

        @Override 
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        { 
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
            for(Exrate_values post : helper.exrates) {

                builder.append("\n\t " + post.getDate()); 
                builder.append("\t \t\t " + post.getFrom_currency()); 
                builder.append("\t \t\t " + post.getTo_Currency()); 
                builder.append("\t \t\t " + post.getExrt_buy()); 
                builder.append("\t \t\t\t " + post.getExrt_sell()); 


                builder.append("\n"); 

        } 
                tvResponse.setText(builder.toString()); 
                pd.dismiss(); 
                }   
        } 

}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When a dialog on an activity is set to visible but on orientation changes the activity itself is destroyed, then it causes leaked window error.

There are two methods to handle this situation:-

**Method 1**

Therefore,you need to `dismiss` dialog in activity's `onStop` or `onDestroy` method. For example:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if(pd!= null)
        pd.dismiss();
}
```

and define dialog in activity class

```
ProgressDialog pd;
```

This link will help you [Handling progress dialogs and orientation changes](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/11/14/handling-progress-dialogs-and-screen-orientation-changes/)

**Method 2**
You have to add this to the activity declaration in the manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

so it looks like

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
        android:name="com.eisuru.abc.MainActivity">
```

The matter is that the system destroys the activity when a change in the configuration occurs. See [ConfigurationChanges](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges).

So putting that in the configuration file avoids the system to destroy your activity. Instead it invokes the `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful comment. I did the second method. It worked very well.

`android:screenOrientation="landscape"`
            `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">`

Comment: @Isuru Happy to help,enjoy coding.

Comment: Method 1 worked perfectly for me. Interesting side note: I already had the orientation declared in the configChanges in my manifest when I was getting the window leak originally.

Comment: Method 1 works perfectly and I would definitely prefer it instead of messing with the manifest file.

Comment: Please check your link "Handling progress dialogs and orientation changes". The linked page shows only advertisement.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to show a Dialog after you've exited an Activity.

The solution is to call dismiss() on the Dialog you created in Example.java:183 before exiting the Activity, e.g. in onPause(). All windows&dialogs should be closed before leaving an Activity.

**Or**

Add this to your manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden
```

Then in your activity add this somewhere:

```
 @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  //ur Code
}
 if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //ur Code
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*dialog is a child that are belong to main thread and if you want to show or kill them you must do this on OnUiThread like this. I am using fragment and when I show dialog, get this exception. But this method save me.*

```
 getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pDialog.show();//dismiss any dialog like this
        }
    });
```

Comment: could you edit your answer and explain how this resolves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I was adding a view in the onResume() of all my activities using WindowManager.addView().  To solve the problem I had to call WindowManager.removeView() in the onPause() of all my activities.